# Не могу разобраться с примером кода из книги python(Django)

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, url

В книге идёт пример с привязкой к url адресу, и у них пример кода такой:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Но у меня в этом же файле находится следующее:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Как мне в МОЙ код переписать тоже самое:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```

?

Answer (score 2):

Практически тоже самое:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),
]
```